# ngx-translate library on angular 13 I get english.json undefined

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

In my home.component.html

```
<span class="form-inline">
                    <select 
                        class="form-control" 
                        #selectedLang 
                        (click)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
                      <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" 
                        [value]="language"
                        [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
                        {{ language }}
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </span> 

<div class="row">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let room of rooms">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="" *ngIf="!room.image1 || room.image1 == undefined; else noimage">
                            <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + 'no-image.png'  }}" alt="student">
                        </div>
                        <ng-template #noimage>
                            <img class="img-list" src="{{ url + 'avatar/' + room.image1 }}" alt="student">
                        </ng-template>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                        <div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
                        <ng-template #thenBlock>     <p class="title-room">{{ room.title }}</p></ng-template>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock> <p class="title-room">{{ room.titleEs }}</p></ng-template>
                        <!-- <p class="title-room">{{ room.title }}</p> -->
                        <div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock2 else elseBlock2"></div>
                        <ng-template #thenBlock2>     <p class="data-room">{{ room.location }}</p></ng-template>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock2> <p class="data-room">{{ room.locationEs }}</p></ng-template>
                        <!-- <p class="data-room"> {{ room.location }}</p> -->
                        <div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock3 else elseBlock3"></div>
                        <ng-template #thenBlock3>     <p class="data-room">{{ room.description | less:[150, '...'] }}</p></ng-template>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock3> <p class="data-room">{{ room.descriptionEs | less:[150, '...'] }}</p></ng-template>
                        <!-- <p class="data-room"> {{ room.description | less:[150, '...'] }}</p> -->
                        <div *ngIf="translateEn == true; then thenBlock4 else elseBlock4"></div>
                        <ng-template #thenBlock4>     <p class="data-room">{{'RoomType' | translate}} {{ room.roomtype }}</p></ng-template>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock4> <p class="data-room">{{'RoomType' | translate}} {{ room.roomtypeEs }}</p></ng-template>
                        <!-- <p class="data-room"> Room type {{ room.roomtype }}</p> -->
                        <p>&#163; {{ room.price }} pm</p>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/room', room._id]" class="btn btn-danger pl-4 pr-4 pt-3 pb-3">View</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

in home.component.ts

```
 public  translateEn:boolean = true;
  public language:string;
 contructor()
{

 this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'es']);
    this. translate.setDefaultLang('es');
}


  switchLang(language: string)
  {


    this.translate.use(language);
    console.log('valor language',this.language);

    //this.translateEn = language === 'en';
    this.translate.currentLang;
    console.log('this.translate.currentlang', this.translate.currentLang);
    if(this.translate.use('en'))
    {
      this.translateEn = true;
    }
    else if(this.translate.use('es'))
    {
      this.translateEn = false;

    }
  }
```

some months ago this component was working not now. I get a GEThttp://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/undefined.json
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

I dont know what it is hapening. I have the good version of ngx library I am using angular 13.

If I change in the constructor     this.translate.setDefaultLang('es'); per     this.translate.setDefaultLang('en'); in the home.component.html the select button doesnt change.

and when I change in the select button en per es or es per en I get  this     console.log('valor language',this.language); = undefined.

Comment: Are you using Http loader, there might be issue in there

Comment: no mate I am not using

Comment: which loader are you using to load you translation file